# Selecting all the <a> elements where content starts with '+'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to select all the  elements where its content starts with + with jquery, how can i do that?

example:

```
<a href="/" >+ Add</a>
```

Comment: Okay so go ahead and do it. This isn't a code generation service.

Comment: If you're able to edit the HTML, then just add `class="add"` to the link then use `$(".add")` to select them. I find it cleaner then having to match on text in an element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) from jQuery:

```
$("a").filter(function() {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML).indexOf("+") === 0;
}). ...
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4rgNw/

Comment: it should be indexOf('+') !== -1

Comment: @rab: nope, the author asked for the elements whose text *starts with* +, which is position 0.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use `$.trim()`? It seems to work without it: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/4rgNw/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as an addition i would like to replace all those elements first character with "-". I cant get it to work with this: '$("a").filter(function () {return $.trim(this.innerHTML).indexOf("+") === 0;}).each(function () {
                                    $(this).replace("+", "-");
                                });'

Comment: @andyE what about using `/^\s*\+/.test( this.innerHTML )` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate, more CSS-driven approach, you can even let your CSS handle adding the plus symbol. Checking a class will scale far better than checking the `innerHTML` of an element, this only really matters if you have a significant amount of + links though.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FPYQx/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="/" class="add">Add</a>
<a href="/" class="add">Add</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.add:before { content:"+ "; }
```

**jQuery**

```
var addLinks = $('.add');

// or pure JS (faster if you only desire the DOM objects)
addLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('add');
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3 there's a :contains() selector that also might be of use.

```
$('a:contains("+ ")').....
```

As an example.. Not exactly what you are looking for, yet might turn out to be useful.

Comment: Nope. `:contains` searches for *existence* in a string, not working for *"starts-with"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = document.links, l = links.length, i, plus = [];
for (i = 0; i < l;i++){
    if(/\+\w/(links[i].textContent))plus.push(links[i]);
};
```

Edit:

```
var links = document.links, l = links.length, i, plus = [];
for (i = 0; i < l;i++){
    if(/\+\w/.test(links[i].textContent))plus.push(links[i]);
};
```

Comment: This code look wrong, you need to execute a function on regex like test or on string with regex as argument like match.